# Determining if case 2 applies of the Master Theorem when a=1, b=2, f(n) = logn

Tags: master-theorem

I'm learning the master theorem and have the following problem:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + log n    
a = 1
b = 2
c = 1
f(n) = log n
Delta = log(1) = 0
    
So the conditions for master theorem are met.

n^Delta = n^0 = 1, which is asymptotically close to f(n) so case 2 applies.

Therefore:    
T(n) in (f(n)logn) = O(logn^2)
```

I feel that I'm doing something wrong.  Can someone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: Sorry, which problem do you mean? What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Fixed it.  It has to do with programming because I'm talking about the Master Theorem for determining complexity of algorithms

Comment: Okay, and what is the problem? Why do you think that you have done something wrong?

Comment: How could it be O(logn)^2 when f(n) is only logn?